# how to add a class at particular child in wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

This is my code and i want to add a class in second child in loop. please tell me how can i do it. i am new in wordpress.

```
<?php
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 3,
          'post_type' => 'hosting_plan',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        query_posts($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
         <div class="hostplbx /*here i want to add class on second child*/">
             <h3><?php the_field('plan_name'); ?></h3>
             <div class="hostprice">
                 <span class="hosprice"><b class="rs"><?php the_field('plan_price'); ?></b> per month</span>
                 <span class="plandetail"><?php the_field('tag_line'); ?></span>
             </div>

             <?php the_content(); ?>

             </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple iterator variable -- some sample code you can alter to apply to your template:

```
$counter = 1;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  if($counter == 2) echo "<div class='second_child_class'>content goes here</div>";
  else echo "<div>content goes here</div>";

  $counter++;

endwhile; endif;
```